# Vlookup returning false as value

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying in include an IF statement to say that if the cell says "PAINT" do one thing and if it says anything else, do another (VLOOKUP) If The cell says PAINT then it works as it should. However, if the cell says anything else then I get a value of "FALSE". I am new to VLOOKUP so I suspect that could very well be the problem.

Thank you

```
=IF(N20="Paint",P20-(VLOOKUP(B20,CODES!$F$2:$G$22,P20-(VLOOKUP(B20,CODES!$J$2:$K$22,2)))))
```

Comment: your `IF` has only 2 arguments, the test and what do you if it's `TRUE` and you haven't specified what to do if it's `FALSE`

Comment: I thought it worked like a normal IF statement where the what to do if true and false is separated by a comma? EG: 

=IF(N19="Paint","this matches","no match found")

Comment: yes it does work like that and there is only 1 comma in your `IF` statement, all other commas are inside `VLOOKUP`

Comment: Okay. I hear what you are saying but I am struggling to figure out how to put the commas in the right place etc. 
=IF(N19="Paint",P19-(VLOOKUP(B19,CODES!$F$2:$G$22,2),P19-(VLOOKUP(B19,CODES!$J$2:$K$22,2)))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do something like

```
 =IF(N20="paint",VLOOKUP(B20,CODES!$F$2:$G$22,2,0),VLOOKUP(B20,CODES!$J$2:$K$22,2,0))
```

At the end of your first VLOOKUP you need to specify which column to return the value from on your 'CODES' sheet, I've pointed to Col G by using '2' and '0' returns an exact match. Then close the 'True' VLOOKUP and start your False VLOOKUP